# How to configure template testing with jenkins email-ext-plugin

Tags: jenkins, email-ext, jelly

Currently I am developing a jelly template, but I am not aware how to configure email-ext-plugin to test the code changes on the created build instead launching the build again and again, just for the sake of testing the template.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should add to the job a Post-Build Action -> Editable Email Notification. Then in the job URL page you will see new "Email Template Testing" link. This link allows you to select a template, and a build number to see what the generated email will look like.
2. The jelly template should be in your Jenkins server $JENKINS_HOME\email-templates folder.

I think [this](https://www.360logica.com/blog/email-notification-in-jenkins/) article will be useful for you. It shows how to configure the SMTP settings in your Jenkins and how to configure the Email-Ext Post Build Action step. We use groovy templates, but I believe it is the same with jelly templates.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat related problem email script developers may encounter is that they do not have permission to access some build result data structures, eg out of the box Jenkins does not give permission to call something like '**getTestResultAction()**. To modify the default permissions goto /scriptApproval. This page lists any prohibited method calls invoked by user scrips and it provides the ability to override the default restrictions.